# SSH connection permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I am trying to login into remote server without password using ssh but I am get the error:

```
Permission denied (public key)
```

To copy .pub key to the server, I had:

```
PasswordAuthentication = yes (in the sshd_config file).
```

After I copied the .pub key, the i disabled the password in the ssh_config I had:

```
PasswordAuthentication = no
```

Now when I tried to ssh:

ssh 'server@192.168.xx.x'

I was getting the error:

```
Permission denied (public key)
```

How can I solve the problem?

I have changed the authorized_keys permission, the .ssh/ permission and so on, but the problem persist. I have even used the ssh-agent $SHELL && ssh-add command.

Comment: Run the ssh on the client with -v, it'll give you more detail of what's happening - and paste that detail here. Also check logs on the server to see if it's rejecting the connection for any reason.

Comment: Also, you say you 'copied the pub key'.... you need to copy the contents of the file, into the accepted_keys file on the server.